How do the switches and level translator work in the LMC7660 Switched Capacitor Voltage Converter
This is the block diagram of Texas Instruments LMC7660:

Here 4 switches are used S1 to S4. The diagram shows source connection of only two transistors S1 and S2, and leaves out the S3 and S4 switch. It makes sense that S1 should be a PMOS as it connects to the higher voltage side. S2 is also logically an NMOS as it connects to ground.
Now the unknown is S3 and S4. S3 is permanently connected to the ground node so it should be an NMOS but the block diagram doesn't show its source pin. S4 is also not obvious for me as its Vout node becomes negative due to the switching action.
I also don't understand why a level translator will work heree and how do they even generate the translation voltage because to turn S4 off its Vgs needs to be zero so whether they use a PMOS or an NMOS, they must be able to generate the same Vg as the Vs present at S4 switch.

The datasheet explains this on page 6:

In the circuit of Figure 11, S1 is a P-channel device and S2, S3, and S4 are N-channel devices. Because the
output is biased below ground, it is important that the p− wells of S3 and S4 never become forward biased with
respect to either their sources or drains. A substrate logic circuit specifies that these p− wells are always held at
the proper voltage. Under all conditions S4 p− well must be at the lowest potential in the circuit. To switch off S4,
a level translator generates VGS4 = 0V, and this is accomplished by biasing the level translator from the S4 p−
well.

The source terminals of these other N-channel FETs aren't marked because they don't have any. Their body contact isn't connected to one of the drain/source terminals, but rather biased to a much lower voltage. This makes those FETs symmetrical, which means that they don't have a defined source and drain. You can use them either way around, and that's also what the circuit does.

Thank you John. Indeed the datasheet does clarify a major part of my question. I am wondering how exactly does the substrate logic and the level translator work to shut down S4. I am curious about this since here we are generating a negative voltage in purely positive voltage system, and to control the switch and to keep its substrate reverse biased we need to get same Vout at gate or even lower voltage at its substrate

@Newbie_Programmer It's quite typical for silicon ICs to contain charge pumps for negative substrate bias, so my guess is that this charge pump IC contains another tiny charge pump to bias itself. The gate driver then uses this negative bias voltage as its "ground". If you really want to know for sure, you could ask TI or decap one of the chips.

That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to reply to my queries. Good day!
